# Copying audio stream from a source file to a trancoded video file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have built my own video-only transcoder using ffmpeg without audio. I do not want to transcode the audio. What will be best way to add the audio stream from the source file to the transcoded file using FFMPEG API?

Answer (score 0):

Try `-acodec copy`, e.g. something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i your_input.file [your video transcoding options] -acodec copy your_output.file
```